# Is there a counterexample that shows that the KL divergence does not satisfy the triangle inequality?

Tags: probability-theory, proof-writing, information-theory

The KL Divergence, or relative entropy for two probability distributions $p,q$ on $\Omega$ is defined as:

$$
H(p|q) = \int_{\Omega} p(\omega) \log \frac{p(\omega)}{q(\omega)} d\omega
$$

This is a divergence and not a distance since it does not satisfy symmetry nor does it satisfy the triangle inequality. I have seen counterexamples for symmetry, but I was wondering if anyone has any simple counterexamples to show that it does not satisfy the triangle inequality.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take $\Omega=\{0,1\}$; $p(0)=1/2$, $q(0)=1/4$, $r(0)=1/10$:

$$
H(p\mid q)+H(q\mid r)\approx 0.24<H(p\mid r)\approx 0.51
$$

($\log$ with base $e$).

Comment: I was wondering why you interpret the triangle inequality that way? can you translate it to the general statement $||x+y|| \le ||x|| + ||y||$ ?

Comment: @dimebucker91 For distance $d$ the triangle inequality is $d(p, r)\le d(p,q)+d(q,r)$. Here we have the opposite...